# Unable to create the selected preference page

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I can't seem to get the android plugin working on eclipse. I installed the ADT Plugin Repository and I've gone to eclipse preferences to set the path to the android SDK but anything with the Android tab comes up with:

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (479).
```

My OS is Ubuntu 15.04 and the computer is too slow to run Android Studio otherwise I'd use that. I've been able to install this on a windows computer easily without issues but this is the first time on Ubuntu.

How can I solve whatever the issue is so I can program android apps on here?

Comment: unless your computer is more that 10 years old, it should still be able to run Android studio, which is not much heavier than eclipse, btw.

Comment: AS is 3x the size of eclipse and this laptop is terrible. I have tried AS on this but it's just too slow.